# add to favorites on youtube video using the api using javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

good morning, I'm making an application using Cordova apache (phonegap) and the application I'm doing requires that you add a video to video list of favorite youtube user, and succeeds in making the login and have the authorization that was not too hard (I'm using ClientLogin validation), but when I go to use the youtube api for this operation did not generate any response, please tell me want where I can find an example that more clearly explain this, I read the documentation youtube api but I failed to understand, me code is:

```
var datos='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
                '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">'+
                    '<id>PYDKDbZr4BU</id>'+
                '</entry>';

$.ajax({
        url:'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/favorites',
        type: 'POST',
        data:datos,
        headers: 'Host: gdata.youtube.com', 
        headers: 'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='+auth+'',
        headers: 'GData-Version: 2',
        headers: 'X-GData-Client: 9720453....c.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        headers: 'X-GData-Key: key=AI39si5uxhyp...YRUS4K6We7CA',
        headers: 'Content-Length: 1941255',
        contentType:'application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(datos){
                                 alert("logro");
                                 console.log(datos)
                               },
        error: function(error){
                var mensaje="";
                for(var x in error){
                    mensaje+=x+" : "+error[x]+'<br>';
                }
                $("#respuesta").html(mensaje);
            }

    });
```

I'm not sure what you are doing this right or not, I clarify I'm not sure of the value that you've put Content-Length since I've drawn from an example, I apologize for my English because I'm Latin and not Spoken English, clarify, generates no response or errors or terminated

Answer (score 0):

[this can help you and is in Spanish](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_favorites?hl=es-ES)

**read**

```
POST /feeds/api/users/default/favorites HTTP/1.1

Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
Authorization: AuthSub token="AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN"
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Client: CLIENT_ID
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>VIDEO_ID</id>
</entry>
```

Comment: as i say, i read all documentation available in the api from youtube, i not understand how  i should do the request of the method 'POST'